# Lucene - apply TokenFilter to a String and get result

Tags: lucene, text-processing

I want to debug Lucene token filters and see results. How is it possible to apply a token filter to a token stream in order to see result?
(using [Lucene 4.10.3](http://lucene.apache.org/core/downloads.html))

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;

public class TokenFilterExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // 1] Create token stream
        StringReader r = new StringReader("Hello World");
        StandardTokenizer s = new StandardTokenizer(r);

        // Create lower-case token filter
        LowerCaseFilter f = new LowerCaseFilter(s);

        // Print result
        System.out.println(??????);

        // close
        f.close();
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

```
    // Print result
    f.reset();
    Iterator it = f.getAttributeClassesIterator();
    while (f.incrementToken()) {
        System.out.println(f
                .getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class));
    }
```